# How do I create a formula to sum values in one column, but multiply those values by a different column?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have two Google Sheets. My main sheet keeps track of meetings (total, or "count"), minutes, and meeting categories:

```
Count    Mins    Category
1        30      Hiring
5        60      Lunch
3        120     Tasks
1        60      Hiring
2        30      Tasks
...
```

And here's the sheet I'm trying to figure out:

```
Categories     Count     Mins
Hiring          2
Lunch           5  
Tasks           5
```

The "Count" column is correct (I'm using a sumif formula), but I'm not sure how to get the "Mins" column and multiply it by the "Count" column. (To get the total meeting time for the Tasks category I need to add (120 * 3) and (30 * 2).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research I stumbled upon SUMPRODUCT and that turned out to be an easy solution. I'm not familiar with "Query" but it looks super powerful. (Is it similar to SQL?)

Anyway, here is my solution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((N6:N1500 = A2),(E6:E1500), (J6:J1500))
```

If the Category in the N column is a match, multiply the value in the E column by the value in the J column. Easy peasy.

Comment: Hi, please accept your answer so it's more visible for others. Thanks.

Comment: Will do. I tried this morning but it said I needed to wait 24 hours. Strangely, I just tried again (some 12 hours later) and it says I need to wait another 23 hours.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A1:C, 
 "select C,sum(A),sum(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by C"), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image]

---

then:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(A1:C, 
 "select C,sum(A),sum(B) 
  where C is not null 
  group by C"), 
 "offset 1", 0), 
 "select Col1,Col2*Col3"), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]